# Does bounded holomorphic function on the unit disc with bounded diameter is bounded by its radius?

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume $f(z)$ is a holomorphic function on the open unit disc $\mathbb{D}$, with 
$d=sup_{z,w \in \mathbb{D}}|f(z)-f(w)|$, $2|f'(0)|=d$, and $f(0)=0$.

What I'm trying to do is to show:
$sup_{z \in \mathbb{D}}|f(z)|\le\frac{d}{2}$

The motivation of this question is from the exercise 7, chapter 2, on Stein's Complex analysis. It said that such a function with $f(0)$ may not be $0$ is linear (but I haven't work it out yet). I think since that statement is true, 
then my question is just a nature clorollary, but it seems not easy to figure out.

Comment: Be aware $d$ may be $\infty$. Technical detail to keep in mind.

Comment: Your actual question is answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/339569/42969

Comment: @MartinR Thanks!